# A question about line length linter 80 characters

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use R in vscode, when the line has more than 80 characters , it will throw a note with a wavy line : **Lines should not be more than 80 characters. line_length_linter**. But i do not find it in lint for R to chage it. Moreover , in the setting.json, I do not know the name of parameter configuration though i search it in the internet.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/de1KA.png)

Answer (score 14):

Just faced the same issue. I found a [workaround suggested for Atom IDE](https://github.com/REditorSupport/atom-ide-r/issues/3#issuecomment-374974483) and it works for VSCode too.

Create a .lintr file in your project folder and add this one line:

```
linters: with_defaults(line_length_linter=line_length_linter(100))
```

For more configuration options, check the [lintr package documentation](https://github.com/jimhester/lintr#available-linters).

Comment: This almost worked for me, however I had to use: 
`linters: linters_with_defaults(line_length_linter=line_length_linter(100))`

Answer (score 1):

I turned it off completely in the .linter file with: `lint_config: with_defaults(line_length_linter = NULL)`.