# lines should not be more than 80 characters. lint_length_linter; Use <-, not =, for assignment.assignment_linter

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, language-server-protocol, lintr

I use R in vscode, it throw many notes with blue wavy underlines, such as 'lines should not be more than 80 characters. lint_length_linte', 'Use <-, not =, for assignment.assignment_linter'.

Creating a '.lintr ' file in the project work for this problem, see [details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481802/a-question-about-line-length-linter-80-characters). And turning off the option **Lsp:Diagnostics** also solve it. But I want to know how to set global settings working for all R projects through modifing certain configure files( like r.json, .Rprofile and so on). I tried but failed.

[some of the problems detected by *lintr*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBNQJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gEVxV.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting a global lintr config file at `~/.lintr` will effect globally.