# Removing wavy warnings about long lines in R-VSCode

Tags: r, visual-studio-code, editor, warnings, lintr

I am running R in Visual Studio Code. I would like to get rid off the `Lines should not be more than 80 characters.line_length_linter` warnings marked as wavy underlines. I would like to get a global effect so that the warnings are removed from all R files I create wherever I want.

Could someone clarify [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68722677/lines-should-not-be-more-than-80-characters-lint-length-linter-use-not) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67481802/a-question-about-line-length-linter-80-characters) discussions a little. I already tried to put the following line:

```
linters: with_defaults(line_length_linter=line_length_linter(10000))
```

in `.lintr` file I created. I tried both locations `R-4.2.2\library\lintr` and `R-4.2.2\library\lintr\R`. In the later one there is the pre-existing `lintr` file without `.`. No help, I also tried:

```
linters: linters_with_defaults(line_length_linter=line_length_linter(10000))
```

and it didn't help either. I tried to relaunch the VSCode after the changes.

Edit: if I put the `.lintr` file with the following line into a higher-level folder of the R script I write, the warnings are gone (the lintr package is installed and is working).

```
linters: linters_with_defaults(line_length_linter=line_length_linter(10000))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it by creating a lintr config file at `~/.lintr` with the following content:

```
linters: linters_with_defaults(
    line_length_linter(10000), 
  )
```